# Aspire E11 ES1-111-M-C1EY, Ubuntu 15.04. won't shotdown

Tags: 14.04, 15.04, shutdown, acer, reboot

Don't know what to do...

My laptop `Acer Aspire E11 ES1-111M-C1EY` hangs at shutdown.
I've already tried to install different versions of Ubuntu (12.04, 14.04, 15.04), but nothing helped.
I've seen a lot of suggestions to change

in  `/etc/default/grub`

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi=off"
```

or something else.

also, i've installed `laptop-mode-tools`, but it hasn't led to anything.
and i added to

```
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

this blacklist `dw_dmac(_core)`

but it still stuck at shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my Acer ES1-111M-P2YU

The issue was that I installed it in legacy boot mode and not UEFI. for whatever reason it didn't want to reboot or shutdown when legacy was set in the Bios.

Once I put the bios back into UEFI it worked fine and no issues with shutdown/reboot since.

In order to get it to work with UEFI for my model, i had to make sure both UEFI and Secure boot were enabled, setup a Bios password, then I installed Ubuntu. once installed I had to go back into the Bios, go into the secure boot settings, and there is a section that let me approve the grub file for boot.

without the last step i was getting a no hard drive detected.

Answer (score 0):

Boot and Shutdown Issues on Aspire E 11 are SOLVED

I had the same issue with my Acer ES1-111M-C1LK

The issue was that I installed it in legacy boot mode and not UEFI. for whatever reason it didn't want to reboot or shutdown when legacy was set in the Bios.

Once I put the bios back into UEFI it worked fine and no issues with shutdown/reboot since.

In order to get it to work with UEFI for my model, i had to make sure both UEFI and Secure boot were enabled, setup a Bios password, then I installed Ubuntu. once installed I had to go back into the Bios, go into the secure boot settings, and there is a section that let me approve the grub file for boot.

without the last step i was getting a no hard drive detected.